# Database entry not created by clicking on the accept friend request button

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I am writing the view for accepting the friend request, I dont know what is happening,
i am fetching jason data to the view but i doesn't working .

i have tried all of the solutions that are on this website but they doesn't work for me

here is my **Javascript**

```
<script >
function acceptFriendRequest(friend_request_id, uiUpdateFunction){
    var url = "{% url 'friend:friend-request-accept' friend_request_id=53252623623632623 %}".replace("53252623623632623", friend_request_id)
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("SUCCESS", data)
            if(data['response'] == "Friend request accepted."){
                // ui is updated
            }
            else if(data['response'] != null){
                alert(data['response'])
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.error("ERROR... this is the error from accept", data)
            alert("Something went wrong")
        },
        complete: function(data){
            uiUpdateFunction()
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my **view**

```
def accept_friend_request(request, *args, **kwargs):
user = request.user
payload = {}
if request.method == "GET" and user.is_authenticated:
    friend_request_id = kwargs.get("friend_request_id")
    # print(f"friend request id {friend_request_id}")
    if friend_request_id:
        friend_request = FriendRequest.objects.get(pk=friend_request_id)
        # print(f"friend request object {friend_request}")
        # confirm that is the correct request
        if friend_request.receiver == user:
            if friend_request: 
                # found the request. Now accept it
                friend_request.accept()
                payload['response'] = "Friend request accepted."

            else:
                payload['response'] = "Something went wrong."
        else:
            payload['response'] = "That is not your request to accept."
    else:
        payload['response'] = "Unable to accept that friend request."
else:
    # should never happen
    payload['response'] = "You must be authenticated to accept a friend request."
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(payload), content_type="application/json")
```

here is the **accept()**

```
def accept(self):
    """
    Accept a friend request
    update both SENDER and RECEIVER friend lists
    """
    receiver_friend_list = FriendList.objects.get(username = self.receiver)
    if receiver_friend_list:
        receiver_friend_list.add_friend(self.sender)
        sender_friend_list = FriendList.objects.get(user = self.sender)
        if sender_friend_list:
            sender_friend_list.add_friend(self.receiver)
            self.is_active = False
            self.save()
```

Comment: what's the source for the accept() function?

Comment: There is a lot of things missing, first, you should not get query params out of kwargs, you should do it from request.GET.get('friend_request_id"). Second, you are making a query using the friend request id search over pk, you need to understand that "pk" points to the table row "id" over the database, so unless you customized that your query is not going to find anything. You have no catch for an error with the query, and you need to paste you error also, as we cannot know what python reports as a problem

Comment: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/friend/friend_request_accept/5/.py 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery-latest.js:9631
ajax @ jquery-latest.js:9176
acceptFriendRequest @ (index):339
triggerAcceptFriendRequest @ (index):326
onclick @ (index):234
(index):354 ERROR... this is the error from accept {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}

Comment: @shivam, you are getting a 404 error (meaning the page you are trying to access do not exists), as you can see, you have a .py at the end of your URL, I think what you are looking for is to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/friend/friend_request_accept/5/ (notice that the end of the URL now doesn't have the ".py"), This is the very peak of the iceberg, django hasn't even executed your request code

Comment: i have removed the .py from the url , still no changes but now no error showing at the consolen

Comment: @shivam no error on the console log means the javascript has successfully sent the request to your django app, you need to check the django logs for the output of that request. I will post an answer once we can really check the output of the django app

Comment: okk i got that the problem was in the accept () thanks for the advice @RonaldPetit

Comment: @shivam I down voted your question, please post the error so I can revert it. Also if you post the error I can help you with that too

Answer (score 0):

I often had the problem that I couldn't see the error message (with PHP) with the Jquery Ajax / json return. Change dataType:"json" to "text" and you may see the error message